# Python 3: with .write not returning any files in directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

For the function below I'm not getting any errors but no files appear in the same directory as where this .py is saved. Does anyone have any ideas for why this is?

```
import itertools 
TAG_RE = re.compile(r'<[^>]+>') 

def remove_tags(text):
    return TAG_RE.sub('', text)

def get_rid_of_html():
    print("removing html tags")
    with open('messages.htm', "r", encoding="utf8") as f:
        lines = f.read()
        print(len(lines))
    lines_removed_html = remove_tags(lines)
    with open('messages_txt_remove_list.txt', 'w', encoding="utf8") as f:
        f.write(lines_removed_html)

get_rid_of_html()
```

Comment: Hey Alecxe. Yes I have called get_rid_of_html() function.

Comment: Please show where you compile `TAG_RE`.

Comment: Check current working directory: `import os os.getcwd()` where `open()` uses for relative paths as you call it.

Comment: @Signal 
import itertools
TAG_RE = re.compile(r'<[^>]+>')

Comment: @FrankJohnLi Put that in your post :)

Comment: @Parfait Excuse me for asking but should I place the open() statement inside the os.getcwd like this os.getcwd(open('messages_txt_remove_list.txt', 'w', encoding="utf8"))

Comment: @Signal will do thanks! :)

Comment: Does a file appear in some other directory instead? Or does no new file appear at all?

Comment: How do you run your program?

Comment: @RobKennedy It does not appear at all

Comment: @RolandSmith get_rid_of_html()

Comment: Then everything but that *one* line of code — the one that calls `open` — is irrelevant. Remove everything else and focus on getting that line to create a file. Once that works, then start adding back the other stuff until you have a complete, working program.

Comment: @FrankJohnLi That is obvious, but not my question. Do you run your code from the command-line or from an IDE like idle?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the **regular expression module** in the code. You need the module for `re.compile(r'<[^>]+>')`:

```
import re
TAG_RE = re.compile(r'<[^>]+>')
```

Also look here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html